# How to record audio in wav format in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, speech-recognition

I have searched everywhere for this and i couldn't find proper way of doing it. I have succeeded in recording in .wav format, but the problem is, when i try reading raw data from recorded .wav file, some chunks are in wrong place/aren't there at all.

My code for recording audio:

```
    func startRecording(){

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try! audioSession.setActive(true)
    audioSession.requestRecordPermission({(allowed: Bool) -> Void in print("Accepted")} )


    let settings: [String : AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey:1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:8,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey:false,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey:false,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue
    ]

    let date = NSDate()

    let df = NSDateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss"

    let dfString = df.stringFromDate(date)

    let fullPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/\(dfString).wav")

    recorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(URL: NSURL(string: fullPath)!, settings: settings)
    recorder.delegate = self
    recorder.prepareToRecord()
    recorder.record()

}
```

When i print out data of recorder audio file, i get weird number where 'd' 'a' 't' 'a' should be written, following by zeros. And then, in middle of of data, it appears.

No 64617461 ('d' 'a' 't' 'a') chunk - it should be in place of 464c4c52
[image]

64617461 ('d' 'a' 't' 'a') at random spot after a lot of zeros
[image: no 64617461 ('d' 'a' 't' 'a')]
[image]

Is there better way of recording wav file? I am not sure why is this happening, so any help would be appreciated. Should i maybe record in other format then convert it to raw?

Thanks and sorry for so many images.

Comment: Can you add a link to a bad wav file?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1fdsu7n2exjr1t/pg-proj-snimak.wav?dl=0 this is just one random example, every wav i record has same problem

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that wav - sounds like there's a problem with your parser. How are you parsing them?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman i am printing before even parsing, the thing i print is just raw NSData of file, before reading actual chunks. I have printed same data for some wav files i downloaded from web, and it printed as expected.

Comment: Are you expecting the chunks in a particular order?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman yes, i mean, there is a "rule" how wav file chunks are ordered (you can see ordering on picture i posted), so you are able to read sample rate, bits per sample etc. Thats why i thought my wav is recording in "bad" format

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: @Xcoder Please give me the solution that is worked for you. I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only the `fmt` chunk is guaranteed to come first. It looks like it's fine to have other chunks before the `data` chunk, so just skip over non-`data` chunks.

From http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

> A RIFF file starts out with a file header followed by a sequence of data chunks.

You need to update your parser :)

Comment: Okay cool, i'll do more research on wav chunks and see what i can do :) thanks for your help

Comment: Okay just did a deeper research, I found out that Apple adds FLLR subchunk inbetween fmt and data chunks. 464c4c52 i was getting is actually 'F' 'L' 'L' 'R' converted from hex to ascii.

Comment: So what is the actual solution?

Comment: What's your question? If you just want to read a wav on iOS try `AVAudioFile`.